# ARC SPARQL Endpoint - Get results in json

Tags: php, json, sparql, php-arc

can anyone help me to figure out how to get query results back in json or xml etc when using the Arc sparql endpoint?

I am using the following code to get the result of my query:

```
$endPoint->handleQueryRequest($query);
$result = $endPoint->getResult();
```

I have looked through the code and tried passing some paramaters - trial and error - but can not get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Its ok, i have figured it out - I was using an endpoint when I should have just been using a store.

It would still be interesting to see how you can query the endpoint directly through a php class - i.e. not through a get or post request - and specify what format the results should be in.

Comment: You could ask @bengee on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a exactly same problems, but with Java. I wanted to use the JSon and also to use the timeout from dbpedia, but Jena (as far as I know) had no solution for this...

Well in the end I didn't use any SPARQL library, and just requested to the whole address (`http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=GRAPH&query=QUERY&...&timeout=TIMEOUT&format=FORMAT`), and it works (of course)